# Draw dashed border inside the custom shape using HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I have to code a shape(below image) in HTML

[image]

And below is the code what I tried so far:

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

h3 {
  height: 100px;
  background: #72bbab;
  border-radius: 50px 10px 10px 50px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h3 i {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  background: #71bbab;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

h3:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h3 i:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h3><i></i>Text</h3>
```

Now the issue is I am not able to remove dashed border of circle from right side. I tried `border-top:0` and `border-right:0` but didn't work.

Thanks in advance

> **Note: Don't want to use any king of image**

Comment: Try border-right: 1px solid #72bbab;

Comment: h3 i:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #72bbab;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

Comment: Since border-right:none' and border-right:0 was not working. I was thinking that you could give border-right: 1px solid #72bbab; so that it looks blended with the green color.

Comment: Thanks for the trick, but again the border of circle and rectangle are not touching each other. Any help for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get the output by keeping same `HTML mark-up` then you have to use many `pseudo selectors`, `CSS calc() function` to calculate `h2 tag width` and many such `properties` to get output using `CSS`.

You have too even use `position` and `z-index` to hide circle border backside of `h2 tag`. And using margin you could arrange the remaining, so at one point whole diagram connects.

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

h3{  
  background:#72bbab;
  width:calc(100% - 95px);
  height:85px;
  margin-left:95px;
  margin-top:21px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  padding-left:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#fff;
}
h3 i{
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background:#72bbab;
  border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  top:2px;
  left:2px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  overflow:hidden;
}
h3 i:before{
  content:"";
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px dashed #fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:8px;
  left:8px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
h3:before{
  content:"";
  width:calc(100% - 120px);
  height:65px;
  border:2px dashed #fff;
  position:absolute;
  right:15px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
h3:after{
  content:"";
  width:3px;
  height:68px;
  background:#72bbab;
  position:absolute;
  top:28px;
  margin-left:-61px;
}
```

```html
<h3><i></i>Text</h3>
```

Comment: This is how you can get custom shape along-with bordered inside and without using any images. Do go through each styling properties to understand well.

Comment: Can you tell me why you used h3:after?

Comment: Yes I will explain you that, remove background property from h3:after and you will find extra added border which is not there in your design, so to overcome that I have used h3:after and replaced that by same background as main background of design. You can delete h3:after and add border individually as in this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n26qpue2/ in h3:before. Adjust bit to get same output.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/induprakash/8ofLjqxm/

I added a higher z-index to rectangle border.

```
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

h3 {
  height: 100px;
  background: #72bbab;
  border-radius: 50px 10px 10px 50px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h3 i {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  background: #71bbab;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

h3:before {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dashed #fff;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 105px;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 2px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-left: 0;
}

h3 i:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
 border-right : 1px solid #72bbab;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, its running as per your image. I have tried a simple and different approach.

JSFiddle Link - https://jsfiddle.net/deepak104080/uwx873x1/

```css
.circle {
  width:130px;
  height:130px;
  border-radius:65px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  background:#71bbab;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.innercircle {
  width:110px;
  height:110px;
  border-radius:55px;
  position:absolute;
  top:9px;
  left:9px;
  z-index:100;
  background:#71bbab;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
}

.tab {
  height: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-left:105px;
  z-index:1000;
  width:350px;
  background:#71bbab;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
.innertab {
  height: 78px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:0px;
  z-index:1000;
  width:340px;
  background:#71bbab;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  border-top: 1px dashed #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
  border-right: 1px dashed #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="circle">
  <div class="innercircle">
  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab">
  <div class="innertab">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not allowed to change the HTML part

Answer (score 0):

Use the `::after` pseudo for `h3` element.

```
h3:after {
  z-index: 9999;
  position:absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 87px;
  background: #71bbab;
  content: '';
  left: 35px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/apyupfwo/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but in your fiddle link the border of circle and rectangle are not touching each other.